# apache2 site conifguration not being applied

Tags: networking, server, apache2, wordpress

sometime ago I configured my local virtual host as sherebiahtishbi.com in my local apache2 and is accessible only within my local network.

I am using Ubuntu 19.10, apache2.4

In my **sites-available** I have **sherebiahtishbi.com.conf** as shown below

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin info@sherebiahtishbi.com
    ServerName sherebiahtishbi.com
    ServerAlias www.sherebiahtishbi.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/sherebiahtishbi.com/wordpress
    #DocumentRoot /var/www/wordpres

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Same exact is in the **/sites-enabled/sherebiahtishbi.com.conf** as well.

previously **DocumentRoot** was pointing to **/var/www/sherebiahtishbi.com/familysite** 
now it is pointing to **/var/www/sherebiahtishbi.com/wordpress** as shown in above virtualhost configuration.

I restarted apache2 service as well but still when go to sherebiahtishbi.com it opens up the home page from old /familysite. I cleared the cache and even restarted my machine but still not able to browse my wordpress site.

I have just setup wordpress in my local apache2 and not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the output of `sudo apachectl configtest`?

Comment: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Syntax OK

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: Added ubuntu and apache version now

Comment: I solved it by following this article https://devanswers.co/installing-apache-ubuntu-18-04-server-virtual-hosts/